# could not determine size if fclose not done twice

Tags: c++, fclose

I'm made a File class that is a sort of wrapper of the FILE type and added some methods.

This is the code of my file class :

```
          #include <Fs/File.h>



File::File(Path& p):
    m_path(p),
    m_openned(false)
{
}

int File::open(const string& mode)
{
    m_f = new FILE;
    fopen(m_path, mode.c_str());
    if (m_f == NULL)
    {
        m_openned = false;
        return -1;
    }
    m_openned = true;
    return 0;
}

bool File::exists()
{
    FILE* file;

    if (file = fopen(m_path, "r"))
    {
        fclose(file);
        return true;
    }

    fclose(file);
    return false;
}

int File::flush(){
    return fflush(m_f);
}

int File::remove()
{
    return ::remove(m_path);
}

int File::close()
{
    if (isOpenned())
    {
        m_openned = false;
        return fclose(m_f);
    }

    return 0;
}

long File::getSize()
{
    struct stat file_status;
    if(!this->exists())
        return -1;
    if (stat(m_path, &file_status) < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return file_status.st_size;
}

FileMode File::getMode()
{
    struct stat file_status;

    if (stat(m_path, &file_status) < 0)
    {
        return FileMode(-1);
    }

    return FileMode(file_status.st_mode);
}



Path File::getPath()
{
    return m_path;
}


bool File::isOpenned()
{
    return m_openned;
}


int File::setMode(FileMode& mode)
{
    return chmod(m_path, mode);
}

int File::renameTo(File& f)
{
    if (f.exists() || !this->exists())
        return -1;

    return rename( m_path , f.getPath());
}

int File::copyTo(File& to)
{
    char ch;
    this->close();
    this->open(FileTypes::READ);
    to.close();
    to.open(FileTypes::WRITE);

    while (!this->eof())
    {
        ch = this->readc();

        if (ch == -1)
            return 0;

        if (!to.eof())
            to.writec(ch);
    }

    if (this->close() < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (to.close() < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int File::readc()
{
    if (!isOpenned())
        return FileTypes::ENDOFFILE;

    char c = fgetc(m_f);

    if (ferror(m_f))
    {
        return FileTypes::ENDOFFILE;
    }

    return c;
}

int File::writec(char c)
{
    if (!isOpenned())
        return -1;

    fputc(c, m_f);

    if (ferror(m_f))
    {
        return FileTypes::ENDOFFILE;
    }

    return 0;
}

bool File::eof()
{
    if (!isOpenned())
        return true;

    return feof(m_f);
}
```

I made some tests and I have a kind of problem

```
            Path p1("test.txt");
    Path p2("temp.txt");

    File f1(p1);
    File f2(p2);

    assert(f1.open(FileTypes::READ) == 0);
    assert(f1.exists() == true);
    assert(f1.close() == 0);

    cout<<"Mode of f1 "<<f1.getMode().getStringMode()<<endl;
    cout<<"Path of f1 "<<f1.getPath().getAbsolutePath()<<endl;
    cout<<"Size of f1 "<<f1.getSize()<<endl;

    assert(f2.exists() == false);
    assert(f1.copyTo(f2) == 0);
            //#####################################
             // If I comment f2.close() the                              
             // assert(f1.getSize() == f2.getSize()) test fails and                  
             // f2.getSize() == 0
             ##########################################
    f2.close();

    assert(f2.exists() == true);
    assert(f1.getSize() == f2.getSize());
```

I couldn't figure why this f2.close is needed because I did a close in the copyTo method.
Can someone help me ?
Thank you in advance.
Ben

Comment: There is always Boost.Filesystem, proposed for C++ TR2.

Comment: In `copyTo`, if `this->close()` fails, you never call `to.close()`.  That's probably not the cause of your problem, though.

Comment: Are you sure that you always reach the `close` in `copyTo` ? It seems that there are many `return` statements there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `File::copyTo`:

```
    if (ch == -1)
        return 0;
```

you are jumping out of the function without properly closing the files. When the target file is not closed, it's contents is probably not sent to the OS, which later reports bogus filesize.

Answer (score 0):

`fclose` flushes the stream.  My guess is, is that without closing the file, the stream has not been fully written, so the sizes are different.  Consider adding `fflush(to);` at the end of your `copyTo` method to ensure everything has been written.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple exits from the copyTo function which doesn't ensure that you actually close the file.  It looks to me that you may be exiting early from the copyTo function and that the intended close isn't executing

```
 while (!this->eof())
{
    ch = this->readc();

    if (ch == -1)
        return 0;

    if (!to.eof())
        to.writec(ch);
}
```

when you hit the end of the file  you will get EOF which in my os (windows) it is -1, which would cause you to return 0 here, and skip the close call.